Fill table td from array list
I have created a table with days and time period.
<?php
$days = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
$times = array('08:00-08:45','08:45-09:00','09:00-09:45','09:45-10:30','11:15-12:00','12:00-12:45');
$columns = count($times);

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Day</th>;";
foreach ($times as $time) {
    echo "<th>$time</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";
foreach ($days as $day) {
    echo("<tr><th>$day</th>");
    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {
        echo "<td></td>";
    }
}
echo "</tr>";
echo("</table>");
?>

Now  I have another subject array to fill the table. Monday to Friday => 6 classes per day = 30 classes and Saturday only four classes. Total 34 classes.
<?php
$subjects = array('Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Comp', 'Comp', 'Comp', 'Comp');
?>

Hindi=8 classes, English=8 classes, Math=6 classes, Evs=8 classes, Computer=4 classes  =>34 classes
Needed: I want to set single subject in every single cell or td daywise or row wise suppose 6 math classes on six days and similarly 8 English classes =>six days in 1st half and 2 classes in 2nd half
What I have done:
<?php
echo "<td>";
$column = count($subjects);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $column; $i++) {
        echo $subjects[$i];
    }
echo "</td>";
?>

Problem is : all the array lists are showing in every td
I am unable to understand how I will set or arrange only one class in each td.

Odd, you cannot echo an array, it will give an error but you say its showing every occurance!!??

how I will set or arrange only one class in each td. You will have to loop over the array, or in this case 3 arrays. You have stored the data in the most unusable form I can thinks of. Maybe your first step should be to rethink how you present this data to the program so it is actually more usable

You can do it like this, by multiplying row index with number of columns plus column index, to access your subjects array: https://3v4l.org/m8urN

@CBroe Most easiest and simple way for the answer. Sir, is it possible to arrange the subjects order row wise or day wise and add conditions?

Are you looking for a result like that :

If yes, here an exemple of code, can be upgrade, depending of the rules.
<?php
$days = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
$times = array('08:00-08:45', '08:45-09:00', '09:00-09:45', '09:45-10:30', '11:15-12:00', '12:00-12:45');
$columns = count($times);
$subjects = array('Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Comp', 'Comp', 'Comp', 'Comp');
$numberSubjects = array();
foreach ($subjects as $value) {
  if (!isset($numberSubjects[$value])) {
    $numberSubjects[$value] = 0;
  }
  $numberSubjects[$value]++;
}
$elmSingleton = array_keys($numberSubjects);
$lastElement = end($elmSingleton);
$fVal = reset($elmSingleton);
$nbUniqSubject = count($numberSubjects);
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Day</th>;";
foreach ($times as $time) {
  echo "<th>$time</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";
foreach ($days as $index => $day) {
echo("<tr><th>$day</th>");
$i = 0;
if (strlen($fVal) == 0) {
    $fVal = reset($elmSingleton);
}
while ($i < $columns) {
    if (($numberSubjects[$fVal] ?? -1) == 0) {
        $secu = 0;
        //Reset tbl element
        $curValIdx = array_flip($elmSingleton)[$fVal];
        unset($elmSingleton[$curValIdx]);
        $fVal = current($elmSingleton);
        while ($numberSubjects[$fVal] != 0 && $secu >= $nbUniqSubject) {
            $fVal = next($elmSingleton);

            if (strlen($fVal) == 0) {
                $fVal = reset($elmSingleton);
            }
            $secu++;
        }
    }
    if (($numberSubjects[$fVal]??-1) > 0) {
        $numberSubjects[$fVal]--;
        echo "<td>" . $fVal . "</td>";
        if ($numberSubjects[$fVal] == 0) { // Remove
            $curValIdx = array_flip($elmSingleton)[$fVal];
            unset($elmSingleton[$curValIdx]);
        }
    } else {
        echo "<td>-</td>";
    }
    $i++;
    $fVal = next($elmSingleton);
    if (strlen($fVal) == 0) {
        $fVal = reset($elmSingleton);
    }
  }
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

Hope is gonna help
To test the code : https://3v4l.org/m8urN
Edit : Or more simple => always take as td element the greatest element
<?php
$days = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
$times = array('08:00-08:45', '08:45-09:00', '09:00-09:45', '09:45-10:30', '11:15-12:00', '12:00-12:45');
$columns = count($times);
$subjects = array('Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Hindi', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Eng', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Evs', 'Comp', 'Comp', 'Comp', 'Comp');
$numberSubjects = array();
foreach ($subjects as $value) {
  if (!isset($numberSubjects[$value])) {
    $numberSubjects[$value] = 0;
  }
  $numberSubjects[$value]++;
}
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Day</th>;";
foreach ($times as $time) {
  echo "<th>$time</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";
foreach ($days as $index => $day) {
echo("<tr><th>$day</th>");
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {
    //Order Value
    arsort($numberSubjects);
    $curValMax = current(array_flip($numberSubjects));
    if ($numberSubjects[$curValMax] > 0) {
        echo "<td>{$curValMax}</td>";
        $numberSubjects[$curValMax]--;
    } else {
        echo "<td></td>";
    }
  }
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

Code test : https://3v4l.org/ubCW3

Thank You for your help. Is it possible to arrange the subjects row wise or add conditions to set the subjects? Actually the problem is that there are eight English classes and I want to set six classes Monday to Saturday first period and rest two classes any days last period.

Hi @achalnaskar, no problem.
I guess you should change your data structure to add rules (I guess multiple rules, example : can get 2 classes on morning, can have full morning classes with same topic, not this classe for this day....)
If i got some free time, will try to make an exemple.
